# imap with php7.0 no working

Tags: apache, imap, symfony, php-7

I have installed on an Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0 the imap extension via:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap
```

then did apache restart. But I still cant call functions like `imap_search()`, I get error

```
Attempted to call function "imap_search" from namespace "PhpImap"
```

`phpinfo()` says about imap:

> Protocols     dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps,
>   ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet,
>   tftp
>
> IMAP  Rex Logan, Mark Musone, Brian Wang, Kaj-Michael Lang, Antoni
>   Pamies Olive, Rasmus Lerdorf, Andrew Skalski, Chuck Hagenbuch, Daniel
>   R Kalowsky

Comment: Posting your full code sample might give you a better response!

Comment: why should I post more code? PHP just dont know the imap_* functions

Comment: what I mean is, its not a problem of the code but of the php/apache. I dont know if imap functions are properly activated already or if I have to enable another mod somehow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
a2enmod imap
```

I'm not certain that's the exact command for Ubuntu.
Here is the documentation:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/a2enmod.8.html

I suspect you have to enable it though.